# How to know which opto-coupler is suitable for high current application?

Tags: power-electronics, opto-isolator, circuit-protection, optoelectronics

I would like a suitable opto-coupler to use as isolation from a 12V and around 30A current and another for 5V and around 30A. Are there any good opto-couplers for those ratings?

Comment: Those are very normal values for optocoupler voltages; but are when you say you want isolation "from" a 12V circuit, what are you trying to isolate from it?  A 3.3V circuit?  220?  1.5kV?  The amp rating is irrelevant unless you are trying to switch it in which case a SSR with a suitable isolation voltage (really a super high power optocoupler) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I am operating multiple servos using 5V high and around 30A and a stepper motor using 12V/30A and I need to isolate it from a few microcontrollers (5V low current) such as nano, drivers etc.. @vir

Comment: At those low voltages, you don't really need to worry about "isolation" in the sense of arc-over or creepage, which is what most optos will help you achieve.  The device you use to drive the loads will certainly have enough isolation to protect your microcontroller.  Your problem is how to drive the high load current.

Comment: why do you think you need an opto-coupler? What performance specs are you expecting?

Answer (score -1):

Opto photodiode (PD) couplers have very non-linear transistor-like qualities with current gain less than 1 that are defined by CTR.  They have insulation ratings typically > 2500V as required by gap from surface isolation input to output by design.  They are linearized by choosing diode input R and output R values to achieve voltage gain but must operate in the linear region above threshold to work best.

To sense low voltage is not a problem and the isolation provides high common-mode rejection which is desirable from switched loads.

To efficiently use the current sensing requires a low shunt R such that it only uses 50mV (std) for full-scale current or 50m/30 Ohms but must consider the power dissipation of 1.5W or an additional 0.4% power loss. Thus choosing a gain factor and satisfying the SNR requirements of a proper current sensor must be defined for the dynamic range of SNR required.

There are dual isolators available for maximum linearity if needed.
Otherwise, the voltage gain is a function of the wide tolerances on the CTR.  Photo transistors (PT) are more sensitive but far worse in CTR tolerances due to hFE tolerances typical with any transistor, so PD's are preferred.

### suggestion

I think with careful design of low side current sensing and voltage amplification using high signal integrity, opto-couplers can be eliminated.

Comment: isolation is not required, but accurate linear current sensing is desired.  Also down-voters who leave no intelligent comments, leave doubt on this answer, yet it is the other way around and reflects poorly on them.